# Private ip iptables rule

Tags: networking, iptables, load-balancing, local-area-network

I am using Windows Azure where they allocate a private IP for you like 10.3.2.1. If I have another machine at 10.3.2.2, how can I open up the first machine(say port 3306) to let the second machine to access it?

Normally I do something like

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 123.2.2.2 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

for using public ip address. But as a newbie I tried to replace the public ip with private ip and it didn't work. :(

Comment: As a non-newbie I would have done the same; should work. Maybe mixed up source and destination? `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 10.3.2.2 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT` that's what you did? Can the systems ping each other? What is the output of `netstat --inet -lnp | grep 3306` on the first system?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact when I add another rule using public ip instead of private ip, it works properly. The right process is listening at that port. So the problem is likely the ip rule.

Comment: Obviously your hosts don't communicate via private IPs. That's not an iptables problem. You see: It's not a good idea not to tell anything about your network configuration. Each such question should come along with the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

What are your default policies on each chain?  What does your network look like?  Are these hosts on the same segment do they go through a firewall, etc.?